# soap wrong xml serialization

Tags: python, xml, soap, suds

I have a wsld definition that looks like

```
...
<sequence>
    <element name="version" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
    <element name="payment" nillable="false" type="tns1:payment"/>
   ...
</sequence>
...
```

This is the xml log of the request that is sent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://impl.ws.payline.experian.com" ...>
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<ns2:Body>
<ns0:doWebPaymentRequest>
<ns0:version>
    <ns0:version>4</ns0:version>
    <ns0:payment>
        <ns1:amount>33300</ns1:amount>
        ...
    </ns0:payment>
</ns0:version>
...
```

So `suds` encloses a `payment` object into `version` (a string), and it breaks the request.
Why is that ?? Any way to go around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering :

suds seems buggy when it comes to setting objects on the fly. But it seems to work fine for sending bare xml.

So what I did is have an xml file and replace part of it with what I need, and send it

```
file: obj.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://impl.ws.payline.experian.com" ...>
 ...
<xxx>REPLACE_ME</xxx>
...
```

and the script :

```
client = Client(url='file://path/to/.wsdl')
xml_request = open('/path/to/obj.xml', 'rb').read()
xml_request = xml_request.replace('REPLACE_ME', value)
result = client.service.TheService(__inject={'msg': xml_request})
```